# Setting up Nant to use dmcs (C# 4.0) on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, nant

Running `Nant -v` on [mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) gives informs me it uses gmcs.exe (C# 2.0).

```
Starting '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/bin/mono ( 
"/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/lib/mono/2.0/gmcs.exe"
```

How to setup Nant to use dmcs.exe (C# 4.0) on Mono?

### ADDED

As is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206905/patching-nant-0-91-to-use-mono-4-0), the newest nightly build supports the mono C# 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that mono-4.0 is not supported for newest version of Nant (0.91 Alpha).

http://nant.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is not supported yet, you should wait for a fix or work out a fix on your own.

If you cannot wait, simply switch to Mono XBuild. http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build

Comment: The newest nant build seems to solve this issue, the web page doesn't update this though.