# Patching nant 0.91 to use mono 4.0

Tags: mono, diff, nant, patch

The [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) doesn't support mono 4, but fortunately there's [a patch for it](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3206199&group_id=31650&atid=402870).

1. I download the patch - http://sourceforge.net/tracker/download.php?group_id=31650&atid=402870&file_id=404197&aid=3206199
2. I also download the [source](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/).
3. I unzip the source and copy the patch inside the directory.
4. I run `patch  < mono-4.0.diff`, but I got this error.

   can't find file to patch at input line 8
   Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?

   ### The text leading up to this was:

   |Index: src/NAnt.Core/Functions/AssemblyFunctions.cs
   |===================================================================
   |RCS file: /cvsroot/nant/nant/src/NAnt.Core/Functions/AssemblyFunctions.cs,v
   |retrieving revision 1.12
   |diff -u -r1.12 AssemblyFunctions.cs
   |--- src/NAnt.Core/Functions/AssemblyFunctions.cs       10 Oct 2005 14:51:26 -0000      1.12

   ### |+++ src/NAnt.Core/Functions/AssemblyFunctions.cs       13 Mar 2011 09:14:40 -0000

   File to patch:

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments, this patch has been merged into the NAnt source tree, wouldn't you be better off to simply use the [latest nightly](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/)? It's been built after the 'already merged' comment.